# Set initial directory as start point for includes from every subfolder in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Lets say my directory structure looks like this:

```
-file1.hpp
-file1.cpp
-file2.hpp
-file2.cpp
-CMakeLists.txt
-dir1
    -file3.hpp
    -file3.cpp
    -file4.hpp
    -file4.cpp
    -dir2
        -file5.hpp
        -file5.cpp
        -file6.hpp
        -file6.cpp
```

Is it possible by using only one CMakeLists.txt in first directory to be able to include files taking always starting point from initial dir? I mean:

file1.cpp:

```
#include "file1.hpp"
#include "dir1/file3.hpp"
#include "dir1/dir2/file5.hpp"

#include "file2.hpp"
```

file3.cpp:

```
#include "file1.hpp"
#include "dir1/file3.hpp"
#include "dir1/dir2/file5.hpp"

#include "dir1/file4.hpp"
```

file5.cpp:

```
#include "file1.hpp"
#include "dir1/file3.hpp"
#include "dir1/dir2/file5.hpp"

#include "dir1/dir2/file6.hpp"
```

also my current CMakeLists.txt sets like this:

```
set(my_SRC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file1.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file2.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dir1/file3.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dir1/file4.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dir1/dir2/file5.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dir1/dir2/file6.cpp
)
```

Comment: What is wrong with including the root directory of your project? E.g. `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: @Tsyvarev It fails at dir1/file3.hpp compilation `No such file #include "dir1/file4.hpp"` . It works for `#include "file4.hpp"` but Id like to provide full path from main directory sine I have all projects made like this

Comment: Do you call `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` from the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`? In that case CMake should include top-level directory, and `dir1/file4.hpp` should be found.

Comment: I had main cmake file one directory farther. When I added `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src` it worked. Thanks problemsolved.